# socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use // python error

Tags: python, flask

if I run my flask server on localhost:5000, when I stop it and restart appear some error: socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use.
For to restart the server I must change the port and run (app.run(debug=True, port=65013)). How I can resolve this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Some other process is using the port. Possibly an existing flask server.

Answer (score 1):

You can search a pid using this port and kill'it, so open your terminal and write :

```
# ps ax | grep 5000     // or # ps ax | grep name_of_service
```

This command will appear a pid of process using this port (ex:3750),then kill this process

```
# kill 3750            // or # killall name_of_service
```